# window switcher comes up behind all other windows

Tags: 14.04, window

I'm using ubuntu 14.04. I recently encountered a problem, where window switcher and also the pop up menu which appears when I right-click on an application appear in the background, i.e, behind all other windows. But the command **alt + tab** in general switches windows. I could see them when I minimized all windows, though. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I'd say file a bug report for Unity